# group 4 dates into one row and sum columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
ID, int PK
PersNo, int
WeekEnding, date
WorkedHours, float
ContractHours float
```

There may be an entry for every staff member for each week for the year or not, most will have 52 entries per year and each WeekEnding date is the sunday.

So I want to group into 4 week pay period and sum the WorkedHours and ContractHours by PersNo.

Data would look like

That would be great...

ample data would be

```
ID, PersNo,WeekEnding, WorkedHours, ContractHours
14, 1234, 1/10/14, 10.50, 20.00
13, 1234, 23/9/14, 11.00, 20.00
12, 1234, 16/9/14, 10.75, 22.00
11, 1234, 9/9/14, 10.50, 22.00
10, 4343, 1/10/14, 11.25, 12.00
 9, 4343, 23/9/14, 11.25, 12.00
 8, 4343, 16/9/14, 11.25, 12.00
 7, 4343, 9/9/14, 11.25, 12.00
```

So each employee may have 52 weeks data per year, but they may start late in the year or leave before the year is up. But all data has WeekEnding dates ie Sundays.

Final output for each employee would be 1 row for each 4 week period as follows;

```
PerNo, 4WkEnding, TotalWorkedHours, TotalContractHours
1234, 1/10/14, 42.75, 82.00
4343, 1/10/14, 45.00, 48.00
```

I think I need to use rownumber or CTE but I am not sure how to proceed.

All help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT PerNo
, MAX(WeekEnding) as 4WkEnding 
, SUM(WorkedHours) as TotalWorkedHours
, SUM(TotalContractHours) as TotalContractHours
FROM myTable
GROUP BY PerNo
, datediff(wk, '01-01-2014', WeekEnding) / 4
ORDER BY PerNo
, datediff(wk, '01-01-2014', WeekEnding) / 4
```

The only tricky thing here is that in the GROUP BY we are grouping by the number of weeks since the start of the year, using integer division of 4 to round it down so that 4 weeks are lumped together. Then in the SELECT list we grab the MAX of the WeekEnding dates to label it in a prettier way.